# How to print add/remove link for user relationships module?

Tags: users

I want to print Add/Remove friend link fro user relationship module on user profile page. I am trying this using below code but its causing white screen.

```
//add link
global $user;
$account = user_load(arg(1));
$actions = _user_relationships_ui_actions_between($user, $account);
if (count($actions)) {
  print theme('item_list', $actions);
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Install Devel module and add dpm statements in a progressive fashion. For instance: After you load the account, add : dmp (arg(1)) (and no other statements following). Inspect the dpm output for correctness and go onto the next statement, ie. dpm($account(arg(1)) and so forth.

Comment: Hi, @J.Reynolds dpm($account(arg(1)) function is not printing anything.

Comment: I assume dpm(arg(1)) worked. Next step is to add dmp after the $account = user_load statement, and then to dpm($account). I made a mistake in saying dpm($account(arg1)) as $account is a std class. You just go by your code snippet above and start with one line then dpm the variable, then onto the next line etc.